# "define() is not defined" error in pdf.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, undefined, pdf.js

I am trying to use pdf.js in my React project to generate thumbnails for an archive of PDFs. In order to use pdfjs, I need to include the main file "pdf.js", which my project will not read because it makes frequent use of a function, "define()", which is undefined. Here is an example of its usage in pdf.js:

```
if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory();
    else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define("pdfjs-dist/build/pdf", [], factory);
    else if(typeof exports === 'object')
        exports["pdfjs-dist/build/pdf"] = factory();
    else
        root["pdfjs-dist/build/pdf"] = root.pdfjsLib = factory();
})
```

How do I address this? I cannot find the documentation for any "define()" function in Javascript.

If I can get these errors to disappear, I would also be grateful for any tips about using PDFJS to generate thumbnails. Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted cannot cause the error you report.

Comment: @Pointy What do you mean? The exact error message is "'define' is not defined. es-lint
(no-undef)" and it points to the code I posted

Comment: The code you posted does not attempt to use the symbol "define" if it cannot be found.